# converting dried measurements to soaked measurements

Tags: soaking

I have a recipe which calls for 250g of tinned black beans.. i thought i would be smart and use some DRIED black beans i have already!

but.. obviously the dried beans will weigh less than the tinned black beans..

How can i calculate how many grams of the dried beans i would need to make 250g of cooked black beans?

I was going to soak them overnight and then boil them until theyre soft!

Comment: This answer covers the general rule of thumb for conversion http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/12861/how-do-i-convert-a-weight-of-dried-chick-peas-to-volume-of-cooked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

250g of canned black beans is about a cup of soaked/cooked beans, which is the same as a drained 15oz/425g tin.

The volume of beans increases from 2-3x. It is probably closer to 3x for black beans but I'm not certain.

So I would cook up about **80g-90g of dry beans**, I think that will get you a bit more than you need without a huge waste. 70g would probably nail it but if I'm wrong you would be short. And I'd take notes on what the weight change is for future reference :-).

Comment: Thank you i will use this! the recipe doesnt have to be exact so im sure having a few extra beans wont matter!